# How to load JSON response into spinner respective to city_id send from android using volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have 1 city spinner in my android code what i have to do is while i am selecting city from city spinner the id of that respective city spinner should go to the server and according to that the area will be display in area spinner the area spinner should be depend on JSON response.For city spinner i have given hard coded string.

**eg.** Whenever i am selecting city nashik from city spinner according to that the area like college road,canada corner should display in area spinner.

**JSON response:**

```
SEARCHED_AREA[{"area_name":"Panchavati"},{"area_name":"Ashok Stambh"}]
```

The code which i have tried:
Spinner spinnerCustom= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCustom);

```
    ArrayList<String> cities = new ArrayList<String>();
    cities.add("Amravati");
    cities.add("Aurangabad");
    cities.add("Kalyan Dombivali");
    cities.add("Mumbai");
    cities.add("Nashik");
    cities.add("Navi Mumbai");
    cities.add("Pune-Pimpri Chinchwad");
    cities.add("Solapur");
    cities.add("Thane");
    CustomSpinnerAdapter customSpinnerAdapter=new CustomSpinnerAdapter(HomeActivity.this,cities);
    spinnerCustom.setAdapter(customSpinnerAdapter);
    spinnerCustom.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             city_id=position+1;
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),"id"  +String.valueOf(city_id) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            registercityid();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}public void registercityid() {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_ID,String.valueOf(city_id));

            return params;

        }

    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

Can anyone please provide sample code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: your objective is not so clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below is sample code, give it a try....

```
public class CityDetailModel {
    String cityName, cityID;

    public CityDetailModel(String cityName, String cityID) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
        this.cityID = cityID;
    }

    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }

    public void setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }

    public String getCityID() {
        return cityID;
    }

    public void setCityID(String cityID) {
        this.cityID = cityID;
    }
}
```

Now add data in your arrayList as below:-

```
    ArrayList<CityDetailModel> cities = new ArrayList<CityDetailModel>();
    cities.add(new CityDetailModel("City1", "CityID 1")); // add appropriate city id according to your requirements
    cities.add(new CityDetailModel("City2", "CityID 2"));
    cities.add(new CityDetailModel("City3", "CityID 3"));
    cities.add(new CityDetailModel("City4", "CityID 4"));
    cities.add(new CityDetailModel("City5", "CityID 5"));
```

Now in onItemSelected() method, get id of that city from your list as below:-

```
Log.e("City ID==>>", cities.get(position).getCityID());
```

Now pass this cityID in your service call and you'll get your area response. Hope it'll help you....

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by following way... follow the instructions and steps on by one.

I have create example of filtering spinner data from state to city. you can do it as per your requirement.

1) first set your state data in spinner adapter in `oncreate()` mehtod.

2) create a method that having city data and also it setting spinner adapter of city.This method actually refreshing your spinner as per state spinner selected value changed. (In your case you can parse your json data here and set into adapter).

```
private void setCity() {

    // String array that having city data.
    String City_gj[] = {"Ahmedabad", "Vadodara", "Surat", "Rajkot"};
    String City_mh[] = {"Mumbai", "Pune", "Lonavala"};
    String City_rj[] = {"Udaipur", "jaipur", "Bikaner", "jaisalmer"};

    // here sp_state is my state spinner. I' getting current selected state value and according to it i am setting my city spinner adapter.
    if (sp_state.getSelectedItem().equals("Gujarat")) {
        ArrayAdapter Adpt_City = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_textview, City_gj);
        //sp_city is my city spinner.
        sp_city.setAdapter(Adpt_City);
    }

    if (sp_state.getSelectedItem().equals("Maharastra")) {
        ArrayAdapter Adpt_City = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_textview, City_mh);
        sp_city.setAdapter(Adpt_City);
    }

    if (sp_state.getSelectedItem().equals("Rajasthan")) {
        ArrayAdapter Adpt_City = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_textview, City_rj);
        sp_city.setAdapter(Adpt_City);
    }
}
```

3) finally, here into `onCreate()` mehthod simple generate your state spinner listner like following and set this `setCity()` method in `onItemSelected`.

```
sp_state.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            setCity();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```